# Android: How to Properly Serialize and Restore State of a Custom View with Transformations

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom view named `MyView`, and I want to serialize its position, width, height, rotation, and other properties after applying transformations to it. The goal is to restore the view's state during the next startup.

I've successfully implemented serialization and deserialization for the view's properties using Gson. However, when I apply the deserialized data to the view, the rotation is not restored. It seems that `matrix.setValues(...)` has no effect, and only the position is applied correctly.

In the provided example below, I generate random transformations for the view and serialize the data. Although the serialization works, applying the deserialized matrix to the view doesn't restore the rotation.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
const val KEY_SERIALIZED_DATA = "KEY_SERIALIZED_DATA"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val preferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val parentLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.parentLayout)

        val myView = MyView(this)
        parentLayout.addView(myView)

        // Restore the previously serialized data if any
        preferences.getString(
            KEY_SERIALIZED_DATA,
            null
        )?.let {
            myView.deserialize(it)
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {

            // Generate random x position
            myView.x = Random.nextInt(
                OFFSET.toInt(),
                parentLayout.width - myView.width.toInt()
            ).toFloat()

            // Generate random y position
            myView.y = Random.nextInt(
                OFFSET.toInt(),
                parentLayout.height - myView.height.toInt()
            ).toFloat()

            // Set pivot point for rotation
            myView.pivotX = 0f
            myView.pivotY = 0f

            // Apply random rotations to the view
            myView.rotation = Random.nextInt(360).toFloat()
            myView.rotation = Random.nextInt(360).toFloat()

            // Serialize the view's properties
            val data = myView.serialize()

            // Save the serialized data in preferences
            preferences
                .edit()
                .putString(KEY_SERIALIZED_DATA, data)
                .apply()

        }
    }
}
```

**MyView.kt**

```
const val OFFSET = 1f

class MyView(context: Context) : View(context) {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    var width = 200f
    var height = 50f

    class SerializedData (
        val x: Float,
        val y: Float,
        val width: Float,
        val height: Float,
        val array: FloatArray
    )

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas.drawRect(OFFSET, OFFSET, width - OFFSET, height - OFFSET, paint)
    }

    private fun getSerializedData() : SerializedData {
        // Get the serialized data object
        return SerializedData(
            x = x,
            y = y,
            width = width,
            height = height,
            array = matrix.array()
        )
    }

    fun serialize() : String {
        return Gson().toJson(getSerializedData())
    }

    fun deserialize(data: String) {
        // Deserialize the data and update the view's properties
        val type = object : TypeToken<SerializedData>() {}.type
        val serializedData: SerializedData = Gson().fromJson(data, type)

        //update this view with the deserialized data
        width = serializedData.width
        height = serializedData.height
        matrix.setValues(serializedData.array)
        x = serializedData.x
        y = serializedData.y
    }
}

fun Matrix.array() = FloatArray(9).apply { getValues(this) }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="Transform and serialize"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have also tried calling `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()`, but it didn't resolve the issue. Any suggestions on how to properly restore the state of the view, including its rotation, would be appreciated.

Note: I'm using the Gson library for serialization/deserialization with the following dependency:

```
implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10")
```